# Space-based scifi probably on Kindle

Tags: story-identification, spaceship

I read a space-based science fiction story most likely on Amazon Kindle.. the most relevant detail was time measured in hours, e.g. a "ten-kay" or 10000 hours was close to a year long. The main character was a fan of ancient earth history and would often convert in his mind (for the readers benefit) to standard Earth time measurements.

@davidbak: No, that's not it. But that does sound interesting, I'll have to check it out. Thanks
@Lorendiac: Aliens, I'm about 90% sure. FTL travel yes, definitely outside our solar system. This was far enough in the future that days, weeks, months, etc held little meaning for the average person in the story, spending all their time on spaceships and nowhere near Earth. I believe he was a fighter pilot, dealing with very high speed space dogfighting maneuvers, though I may be confusing that with another story.

Comment: Might be [_A Deepness In The Sky_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Deepness_in_the_Sky) by Vinge.  Main character wasn't exactly a "fan" of ancient earth history - he was _from_ ancient earth history (in a story told in the far far future).  A common unit of time was the "msec" or million seconds ~ 11.5 days, also "ksec" was used, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Deepness_in_the_Sky#Interstellar_culture).  But I don't recall the main character ever converting it "in his mind" and they didn't use hours - so, maybe not.

Comment: I can think of at least one other possibility, but I'd really appreciate it if you could give us a bit more detail first. Do you remember anything about what the main character was actually trying *to do* as part of the plot, when he wasn't just amusing himself by thinking about Earth's history and its old timekeeping system? Were there sentient aliens in the story? Faster-than-light travel? Had the human race even gotten from here to other solar systems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be talking about Mark Kalina's "Hegemony". The book is about pilots who can transfer their consciousness into robot fighters that ride lasers into battle so they can survive dozens of gee of acceleration. They use "ten-kay" as a unit of time. They don't really convert it on the fly though after explaining what it is initially. The main characters are also mostly female, though there are a few male ones.

Comment: That's the one! He was captain of a freight liner, not a fighter, so that detail was wrong among others. A relevant paragraph:

Comment: The two megaton freight-liner Ulia's Flower was an old ship, older than Rilk, who was on the wrong side of five hundred thousand hours himself; sixty , in Old-Earth years, though Old-Earth years were a fading measurement. Old-Earth history was a hobby of his... though if pressed, Rilk would admit that Old-Earth had very little to do with humanity now.

Comment: @Neil oh yeah, I had mostly forgotten about that guy. Glad this was the book, it is a good one. Just goes to show that scant details still work so long as they are the RIGHT scant details :)